# Google Form submit issue

Tags: google-forms

When I was trying submit my google form or upload a file, I see that "There is a problem. Please try again.."

This issue only gets fixed when my Google Cloud is cleared.

Why can't I fill out a form when my account's storage is full?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process of the file upload of Google Form works as follows:

1. File is uploaded to your (respondent's) Google Drive
2. Ownership is transferred to the form owner
3. Sharing is removed from you

As you could see, you are required to have enough space to upload the file to your Google Drive.